# How would one prove that $\zeta(3)<\frac{\pi^2}{28}+\frac{\pi^3}{21\sqrt3}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, inequality

I recently encountered the following two inequalities involving $\zeta(3)=1.2020569\dots$

> 1. $$\zeta(3)<\frac{\pi^2}{21}+\frac{\pi^3}{42}=1.208225\dots $$

and

> 2. $$\zeta(3)<\frac{\pi^2}{28}+\frac{\pi^3}{21\sqrt3}=1.204937\dots$$

The proof I have relies completely on integrals and the use of some mean inequalities, getting these two inequalities as **side results**.

However, the bounds are not very strict, so I wonder if there is some other more efficient way to get at least one of the two results.

Any ideas?

Comment: It really depends what you're trying to do. I suspect you're looking for an elegant way to directly show these inequalities; however the precise form of the fractions in $\pi$ presumably comes from the integrals and is likely to be strongly linked to that derivation. You say you want "efficient"; an efficient but ugly approach is to note that $\frac{1}{n^3}<\frac{1}{n^3-n}$ for all $n>1$. So for any $N>1$, $\zeta(3)<\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^3} + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3-n}$. We can work out the second sum exactly; in fact $\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3-n} = \frac{1}{2N(N+1)}$...

Comment: ...so $\zeta(3)<\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^3}+\frac{1}{2N(N+1)}$ and even taking $N=3$ gives $\zeta(3)<1.2037\ldots$.